# What tool to use for ui testing for teamcenter like windows apps?

Tags: automated-testing, uiautomation

I was trying to conduct ui testing on teamcenter and similar windows apps. I found selenium but it only works in the browser. What is the best way to test the UI for an app which we do not have the source code to, a windows app. I want to click on various UI elements and compare expected vs actual output on screen. Off the shelf tools are preferable.

Comment: What kind of budget do you have? There are off the shelf tools that can do what you require but they can be quite expensive.

Comment: I dont know how to quantify it but there we have a rather large budget.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of UI testing tools that can work for you: TestAnywhere and TestComplete are two that I have personally worked with.

A quick search found this list: https://www.askui.com/blog-posts/top-10-automation-tools-for-desktop-applications-windows

Beyond that, the best tool for your needs is something you will need to decide on. I'd suggest taking some time to build a list of essential features, and features that would be nice to have. Once you have that, start researching tools to find two or three that have all your essentials and a decent selection of your nice to have items.

Your final step is to evaluate how your candidates perform with the software you're testing.

There really is no "best choice" when it comes to determining what tools to use: only a choice that will work for you, your team, and your team's skills.

Answer (score -1):

There are various software testing tools that can be used for conducting UI testing especially for which we do not have the source code to a windows app.
One testing tool that various companies recommend and use is SikuliX

SikuliX is a tool that can be used to automate anything on any of the desktop computers having OS either Windows, Mac or some Linux/Unix. SikuliX is powered by OpenCV and uses image recognition to identify GUI components. This is useful in cases when there is no easy access to  source code of the application or web page.

Following are the scripting languages that are supported by SikuliX which could provide diversified automation scripting languages for testers

1. Java programming
2. Python language level 2.7
3. Ruby language level 1.9 and 2.0
4. JavaScript